# ASP.NET Core Xml serialize data anotation XmlIgnore

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, .net-core, data-annotations, xmlignore

I am looking for some equivalent for [XmlIgnore] anotation from .NET framework 4.6 in .NET Core. Any Ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Install nuget package `System.Xml.Serialization`.